# Opening .lpk in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, convert, file-formats, layer-package

I am brand new to QGIS.

I have downloaded the BLM's public land survey system from their website (https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/blm-national-public-land-survey-system-polygons), which has a file format of .lpk.

I cannot seem to open that file format in QGIS.

Anyone know how to get around this problem?